# How to change behaviour of the method in groovy using that method in metaclass

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I would like to "spoil" plus method in Groovy in the following way:

```
Integer.metaClass.plus {Integer n -> delegate + n + 1}
assert 2+2 == 5
```

I am getting StackOverflowException (which is not surprising).

Is there any way to use "original" plus method inside metaclass' closure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The groovy idiomatic way is to save a reference to the old method and invoke it inside the new one.

```
def oldPlus = Integer.metaClass.getMetaMethod("plus", [Integer] as Class[])

Integer.metaClass.plus = { Integer n ->
    return oldPlus.invoke(oldPlus.invoke(delegate, n), 1)        
}

assert 5 == 2 + 2
```

This isn't actually that well documented and I was planning on putting up a blog post about this exact topic either tonight or tomorrow :).

Answer (score 1):

Use this to "spoil" plus method:

```
Integer.metaClass.plus {Integer n -> delegate - (-n) - (-1)}
assert 2+2 == 5
```

Not surprisingly, using '+' operator in overloading plus method will result in StackOverflow, it is required to use something other then '+' operator.

Other mechanism: Use XOR or some bit operator magic.

Regards,
Peacefulfire

Comment: It seems that Groovy 1.6 is clever enough to change the call delegate - (-n) to delegate + n and StackOverflowException is still thrown

Comment: hmm.. My version is Groovy 1.6 and Java 1.5.0_15 
I ran that in groovy console and it ran fine without throwing any StackOverflowException

I ran in groovyshell and it ran fine. 

How are you trying to run above script?

Comment: Just saw the answer posted above by Ted. I think that is far better and general solution. +1 to Ted.