# How do I reset a mocked static method in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have the following in the test setup:

```
    def originalPostAsXml = RestClient.&postAsXml

    RestClient.metaClass.'static'.postAsXml = {
        String uriPath, String xml ->
        return 65536
    }
```

and in the test cleanup:

```
    RestClient.metaClass.'static'.postAsXml = originalPostAsXml
```

But when the next test runs, when it tries to execute RestClient.postAsXml, it runs into a StackOverflowError:

```
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:282)
```

It looks like RestClient.postAsXml recursively points to itself.  What's the right way to reset a mocked-out static method?

Comment: Here's a previous similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920582/how-to-change-behaviour-of-the-methed-in-groovy-using-that-method-in-metaclass

Comment: You can reset the metaclass - See this question which has answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612569/how-do-i-undo-meta-class-changes-after-executing-groovyshell

Answer (score 6):

In a unit test, I often set the metaclass to `null` in the `tearDown()` which seems to allow the class to work as it did originally without my modifications.

example:

```
void setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    ServerInstanceSettings.metaClass.'static'.list = {
        def settings = [someSetting:'myOverride'] as ServerInstanceSettings
        return [settings]
    }
}

void tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
    ServerInstanceSettings.metaClass.'static'.list = null
}
```

If you are using JUnit4 you can use `@AfterClass` instead in this case which makes more sense perhaps.

Answer (score 4):

I find that simply setting `<Class>.metaClass = null` works for me.

Spock Example:

```
def "mockStatic Test"(){
  given:
  RestClient.metaClass.static.postAsXml = {
    String uriPath, String xml ->
    return 65536
  }

  when:
  //some call that depends on RestClient.postAsXml

  then:
  //Expected outcomes

  cleanup:
  //reset metaclass
  RestClient.metaClass = null
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm using Spock too and setting Class.metaClass.'static'.method to null didn't work but setting Class.metaClass to null did.

Answer (score 1):

schmolly159's hint above led me to the following solution:

```
    def originalPostAsXml = RestClient.metaClass.getMetaMethod('postAsXml', [String, String] as Class[])
```

then to reset the method:

```
    RestClient.metaClass.'static'.postAsXml = { String uriPath, String xml ->
        originalPostAsXml.invoke(delegate, uriPath, xml)
    }
```